# How can I use data from other columns in SQL?

Tags: java, sql, variables

I am trying to use calculations from previous columns in SQL. I tried using variables but had no luck. Here is what i have now:

```
CREATE VIEW CalculationsTable (id, deltaLat, deltaLon, a, c, d) AS 
  SELECT Resource.id, 
    RADIANS("+lat+"-Resource.lat) AS deltaLat, 
    RADIANS("+lon+"-Resource.lon) AS deltaLon,
    (SIN(deltaLat/2)*SIN(deltaLat/2)) + COS("+lat+") 
       * cos(Resource.lat) * (SIN(deltaLon/2)
       * SIN(deltaLon/2)) AS a, 
    2 * ATAN2(SQRT(a), SQRT(1-a)) AS c, 
    6371 *c AS d 
  FROM Resource AS Resource;
```

I keep on getting this error:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'deltaLat' in 'field list'

The `deltaLat` in the error is the `deltaLat` from this part of the code `"(SIN(deltaLat/2)..."`

Comment: Can you give us a hint of what's wrong with what you have now? Generates an error? Gives the wrong values? Something else?

Comment: I keep on getting this error:
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'deltaLat' in 'field list'

The deltaLat is the deltaLat from this part of the code "(SIN(deltaLat/2)..."

Comment: Something is wrong with your closing bracket "");"

Comment: Ah, sorry about that, pasted some extra code. The closing bracket is from something else: method("SQL STATEMENT");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to reformat your query and use a subtable. E.g.

```
SELECT calcValueA + 3,
  FROM (SELECT A + B calcValueA FROM yourTable);
```

For your query you have to do it several times.

Comment: hmm.. do you mean creating separate views for every calculation?

Comment: No do a query like the above one. You have to do the subquery for each of your calculations I guess. Make sure you pass through your already calculated columns each time.

Answer (score 0):

At the point where your calculation is being done the columns deltaLat and deltaLon have not been aliased so you can't refer to them. You need to wrap the aliased columns in their own query and then use that as a subquery. I've had a go at it below (just in the editor), even if it doesn't work you should get the general idea!

Incidently, I've left your quoted terms in - no idea what they are meant to do

```
CREATE VIEW CalculationsTable (id, deltaLat, deltaLon, a, c, d) AS 
SELECT id, 
       deltaLat,
       deltaLon,
       a,
       c,
       6371 * c AS d 
FROM (
       SELECT id, 
              deltaLat,
              deltaLon,
              a,
              2 * ATAN2(SQRT(a), SQRT(1-a)) AS c
       FROM (
              SELECT id, 
                     deltaLat,
                     deltaLon,
                     (SIN(deltaLat/2)*SIN(deltaLat/2)) + COS("+lat+") 
                        * cos(lat) * (SIN(deltaLon/2)
                        * SIN(deltaLon/2)) AS a 
              FROM ( 
                     SELECT id, 
                            RADIANS("+lat+"-Resource.lat) AS deltaLat, 
                            RADIANS("+lon+"-Resource.lon) AS deltaLon
                            Resource.lat as lat
                     FROM Resource 
                   )
            )
     )
```

Comment: Ah, I get what you are trying to do here and this makes much more sense. Thanks for the help Dave! I'll try this out in my code.